# Get Duplicates and Update Column in Different Table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

Poems:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|  id  |        poem        |        author       |
---------------------------------------------------
|   1  |   Blah blah Hey    |       Jane Doe      |
---------------------------------------------------
|   1  |   Yo yo Hey Bla    |       Jane Doe      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Authors:

```
-----------------------------
|  id  |        name        |
-----------------------------
|   0  |                    |
-----------------------------
```

I want to remove the duplicates from the poems table and populate the newly created authors table. Ideally, I'd like to then update the authors (or create a new authors_id) column in poems table with author.id

I know that the following code *shows* me the duplicates,

```
SELECT author, COUNT(*) 
FROM poem
GROUP BY author
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

But how do I add them to the author.names column?

Also, will this code help me with the next part?

```
ALTER TABLE poem
     ADD COLUMN author_id serial,
     ADD CONSTRAINT author_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES author (id) MATCH FULL;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a unique ID, you can use Postgres' `distinct on` operator:

```
insert into Authors (id, author)
select distinct on (id) id, author
from Poems
order by id
```

This will pick the first ID from the `poems` table for each author. Another alternative is to setup the poems table with a serial column:

If you have setup the `id` column as a serial column you shouldn't supply the value in the first place, just use:

```
insert into Authors (author)
select distinct author
from Poems;
```

By not specifying the `id` column, it will be populated automatically (*if* it is defined as `serial`)

But this:

> ALTER TABLE poem
>       ADD COLUMN author_id serial,
>       ADD CONSTRAINT author_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES author (id) MATCH FULL;

doesn't make sense. If you define the column as `serial` it will be incremented automatically each time you insert a row that doesn't specify a value for the column. How is that going to reference the `id` column of the `authors` table? I can't image *any* situation where it makes sense to define foreign key column as a `serial`

Once you have populated the `authors` table you do need to add an `author_id` column to the `poem` table, but it should ***not*** be a serial column:

```
ALTER TABLE poem
   ADD COLUMN author_id integer,
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id);
```

Once you have that you can run an update:

```
update poem
  set author_id = author.id
from author 
where author.name = poem.author;
```

After that you can drop the `poem.author` table.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/79b13/1

Comment: It is defined as serial! I should have probably mentioned that. Any idea how to define the authors in the poem.author column as a foreign key and then repopulate it with the poem.id? Either that or create a new poem.author_id column and populate it that way...

Comment: Ahh, yes I see that mistake. What would it need to be then as the foreign key. An int?

Comment: I have added a SQLFiddle example. Note that your `add foreign key` was wrong as well.

Comment: Thank you again. I was actually having problems with it and was trying to figure out why before I asked you again. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting from a select statement. For example like this:

```
    insert into Authors (id, author)
    select distinct id, author
    from Poems
```

Comment: Close! If you remove the `id` columns I get the duplicates removed. If I keep the `id`, then I get distinct id values put into author as well, which I don't want because some authors have different ids in poems.